# AFNetworking 3.0 - wrong authorization code

Tags: ios, objective-c, http-response-codes, afnetworking-3

I'm using AFHTTPSessionManager to GET request with authorization headers;

In case of wrong user/password server according to postman is returning  content type : text/html with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Apache Tomcat/8.0.21 - Error report</title>
        <style type="text/css">H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}.line {height: 1px; background-color: #525D76; border: none;}</style> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>HTTP Status 401 - Błąd podczas autentykacji</h1>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <p>
            <b>type</b> Status report
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>message</b>
            <u>Błąd podczas autentykacji</u>
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>description</b>
            <u>This request requires HTTP authentication.</u>
        </p>
        <hr class="line">
        <h3>Apache Tomcat/8.0.21</h3>
    </body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately NSURLSessionDataTask returns

```
NSHTTPURLResponse *test = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)task.response;
 NSLog (@"Status code, %i", test.statusCode);
```

returns Status code, 500

as well as NSError

```
  NSString* errorResponse = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:(NSData *)error.userInfo[AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseDataErrorKey] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Error response: %@", errorResponse);
```

returns Error response: {"error":{"code":"UNKNOWN_ERROR","details":null,"description":"Server error","version":0}}

This is my get operation method.

```
- (void)getOperationForAction:(NSString *)action
                   parameters:(NSArray *)params
                   completion:(id (^)(id json, BOOL success))completion {
    NSURL *url = [self apiUrlForAction:action params:params.mutableCopy];
    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [self sessionManager];

    [manager GET: url.absoluteString parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);

        if (completion) {
            completion(responseObject, YES);
        }
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
        NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:(NSData *)error.userInfo[NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestionErrorKey] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        if(responseString != nil && ![responseString isEqualToString: @""]) {
            NSData *JSONData = [responseString dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            id responseJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:JSONData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
            if(responseJSON != nil) {

            }
        }

        NSHTTPURLResponse *test = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)task.response;
        NSLog (@"Status code, %i", test.statusCode);

        NSString* errorResponse = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:(NSData *)error.userInfo[AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseDataErrorKey] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Error response: %@", errorResponse);

        ApiError *apiError = [[ApiError alloc] initWithString:errorResponse error:nil];

        completion(apiError, NO);
    }];
}
```

Request is handled correctly - the 401 issues appeared when I was intentionally using wrong auth login/password just to check the response errors. The problem is with incorrect status code as mentioned before.

@Edit
for

```
    NSHTTPURLResponse *test = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)task.response;
    NSLog (@"Status code, %i", test.statusCode);
    NSLog (@"Error code, %i", error.code);
    NSLog (@"Error domain, %@", error.domain);
```

Status code, 500
Error code, -1011
Error domain, com.alamofire.error.serialization.response

Comment: What is the status code returned when testing with Postman? If it's a 500, then it's the same as you're seeing in AFNetworking, which means there's nothing wrong with your AFNetworking usage. The server is returning a 500 for a situation where you'd have preferred a 401. Unless you have control over the server, you're going to just have to deal with it (parse the body of the 500 response to look for the embedded 401 status, for example).

Comment: As I said: postman status code is 401. 
As well as body as you can see up there.

Using the old version of AFNetworking with AFHTTPRequestOperation got status code 401.

Comment: The 500 means "Internal Server Error". It's possible that the server wanted to render the 401 error but encountered an error _while generating the error_. Check the server logs. Also, to debug things like that I recommend you learn to use Wireshark or a different network capturing software to analyze what's actually sent over the wire: if you inspect the HTTP response in Wireshark you're likely to see an error code 500 in the response packet (it's highly unlikely that AFNetworking has a severe error parsing the response code, especially since it's wrapping the Cocoa classes).

Comment: Guys :) Just to be strict. I know what each status code mean. I'm presenting you all returned data from request with pure postman and URLReposponse/NSError from my ApiClass using AFNetworking 3.0. 

So your comments about wiresharks and error while generating error are useless. Server is giving my correct response with 401 (checked via postman) but I'm or AFNetworking is handling this error in a wrong way. 

Focus of AFNetworking - error handle possible problems, not on server side.

Server side is as well checked via android/WP apps - it's returning 401.

Comment: No, actually, you did not mention that postman was returning a 401. The body of the response, which you did paste into your question, happens to have a 401 mentioned in it. That doesn't mean the actual HTTP status code is also a 401. Now that you're saying postman does return a 401, and mentioned for the first time that you were getting a 401 from AFNetworking 2.x, perhaps you should show us the AFNetworking 3.x version of the code you wrote.

Comment: The HTTP response _status code_ and _body_ can be different, which is likely the reason for what you're seeing. When you say _"server is giving my correct response"_, have you checked what's really sent? Or have you checked what the logs say has been sent? Again, it's highly unlikely that AFNetworking is mis-parsing the HTTP status code, because that's actually done by iOS  system code (and really trivial).